# Local Notifications 2023. How to set periodically notifications?

Tags: flutter, duration, flutter-local-notification

I'm working in an app and I need to implement local notification based on user input. This means that the user will select when the app shows the notification. I found the method [repeatInterval](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/latest/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/RepeatInterval.html), but it only offers fixed time intervals such as

> everyMinute → const RepeatInterval

> hourly → const RepeatInterval

> daily → const RepeatInterval

> weekly → const RepeatInterval

I don't need these options, because they are fixed.
I need to add a notification, and the interval on runtime.

I tried with,

```dart
NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
 NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  -1,
  title,
  body,
  tz.TZDateTime.from(
    DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours:  hours)), 
    tz.local
  ),
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
  notificationDetails,
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime
);
```

With this method I was able to pass manually the first notification, but I need to repeat the notification X times until the user cancel the notification.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flutter_local_notifications` plugin does not provide this functionality by itself. You have the following options.

- You could create your own fork of the plugin and create variants of the `periodically_show` function. The [android implementation](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/21a787d5b47abf84cac854158621cfeb3656ace2/flutter_local_notifications/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java#L625) and [iOS implementation](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/238068076ae0859be6e3961bec9a5e3d948757e2/flutter_local_notifications/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m#L699) of `periodically_show` internally support any time interval. It's just the API design of the plugin that choses to hide this functionality.
- You could combine `flutter_local_notifications` with a background worker library `WorkerManager` that allows your app to execute some functionality in the background. On each call you could schedule a notification.
- You could calculate the scheduling time X times in advance and schedule your notifications in batch. Then, when the user changes their notification preferences, you can cancel them all again.

I think such functionality would make a great contribution to the `flutter_local_notifications` library.

Comment: Thanks you @jraufeisen, I just implemented `WorkManager`. I'm still trying to understand how it runs, seems that all is working correctly.